# I want to change css background url by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background url of image by javascript now in other tutorials they have the image downloaded in the desktop and just give its path but in my case the user will give a image link in input area and it should display inside of that url

```
let imglink = document.getElementById("img_link").value
document.getElementById("imgPreview").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imglink + ')'
```

I know my code is wrong and weird but I need proper solution how i can put that link inside that url. PLEASE dont do too much hard coding bcz I am a beginner it will hard for me to understand

Comment: What is supposed to be wrong with that code? As long as you execute it at an appropriate point, I don't immediately spot anything that should make this _not_ work ...?

Comment: you need to wrap the code in a change/input/paste event on the input, else it will just fire once onload not when you type

Comment: Consider adding other part of your code as well. That can really helps us see what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```js
'url(' + img_link + ')'
```

to

```js
'url("' + img_link + '")'
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

document.getElementById("imgPreview").style.backgroundImage = url(img_link)

Comment: no it is not working